# Media queries rule loading on incorrect browser size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have 4 images and i want them to be displayed in one row at 1200px
then 992px and lower i want 2 pictures displayed in one and other 2 should go in next row and at 768px and lower i want one picture in one row.

Problem occours when browser is at less than 992px  chrome just loads 768px rules.

**HTML**

```
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img/g1.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/g2.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/g3.png" alt="">
    <img src="img/g4.png" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .gallery img {
    width: 51%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .gallery img {
    width: 49%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .gallery img {
    width: 24%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Seems like the width in the 768px rule should be 100%, or am I misunderstandng your question?

Answer (score 0):

> Problem occours when browser is at less than 992px chrome just loads 768px rules.
>   Sure, because the 768 rule contains `min-width: 768px`, the 992px rule contains `min-width: 992px`

So on a 900px wide screen `min-width: 768px` rules will apply, since it's less than  `min-width: 992px`

I suppose you should use `max-width` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to start from the smallest screen size and work my way up (that's the way that Bootstrap does it). So, your smallest screen size doesn't need a media query since it's what will be set by default.

```
.gallery img {
  width: 51%;
}
```

Then, you can put your next rule in the `min-width:768px` rule. Once the screen hits 768px, switch to two images per row

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .gallery img {
    width: 49%;
  }
}
```

Finally, move your last rule to the `min-width:992px` rule. Once the screen hits 992px, switch to all four images in one row

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .gallery img {
    width: 49%;
  }
}
```

So, all together

```
.gallery img {
  width: 51%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .gallery img {
    width: 49%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .gallery img {
    width: 24%;
  }
}
```

Check out this codepen for a demo: https://codepen.io/noahjwhitmore/pen/MrBdMY